# Using UIHint on an enum value to display custom template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, enums

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public Device 
{
    public DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
}

public enum DeviceType
{
    [Display(Name = @"Windows")]
    [UIHint("DesktopDevice")]
    Windows,
    [Display(Name = @"iOS")]
    [UIHint("MobileDevice")]
    iPhone,
}
```

I also created `Shared/DisplayTemplates/DesktopDevice.cshtml` and `Shared/DisplayTemplates/MobileDevice.cshtml`.

I would like to use the `UIHint` to tell Razor which template to use. This doesn't seem to be happening. Am I misusing `UIHint`? Can it only be used at the enum declaration instead of the enum value level? Is there something else I need to do to make it work or is my approach completely off?

Comment: In cases like this, I use UIHint in the property declaration and a single template (something like `DisplayDevice.cshtml`) for all enum options. Then, inside the template, I test the `Model` value in a condition scope to render the corresponding template for each enum value.